# How to add new columns to ftable?

Tags: r

I have some troubles creating additional columns which shows the percentage of those who voted and those who did not vote in different columns for each combination of the other factors. I tried with

```
ftable<-ftable(table)
ftable(100*(prop.table(ftable)) but its looks awful
```

Could some one provide any help?

```
                                       gender       Male     Female
```

voted     education      age      race                    4          4

no        grade school  18-24     white

```
                              negro                   1          2

                              other                   0          0

                    25-34     white                   6          13

                              negro                   2          2

                              other                   0          0
```

yes        grade school 18-24     white                   10         5

```
                              negro                   2           5

                              other                   2           4
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the package gmodels and the CrossTable can help you. You can get the diferents percentages for each variable.

For example:

```
library(gmodels)
CrossTable(mydata$education,mydata$gender,format="SPSS")
```